# Скрипт подстановки месторасположения

Tags: json, javascript

Мне надо реализовать следующее.

Пользователь начинает вводить название города или страны, я получаю ввод и автоматически подставляю место расположения. Естественно, мне интересно, где найти саму базу городов и стран? Желательно на русском языке.

Мне надо отображать расстояние от пользователя, по месту нахождения, до другого района города в заданной стране.

Думаю, что есть готовые решения. По скольку тема для меня новая, не знаю даже куда смотреть.

*Обновление:* Интересно бы посмотреть на скрипт с районами городов. Все это богатство лучше запрашивать с проверенных серверов, те я не хочу держать это локально. Идеальный вариант использовать какую-либо службу гугла.

*Обновление 2:* По сути предлагают одно и тоже - скачать базу и по не запрашивать. Мне же нужен сервис, на вроде яндекс карт, к которому можно обратиться, передав строку ввода, а на выходе получить наиболее подходящий вариант расположения.

*Обновление 3:* Пока остановился на картах яндекса. Буду использовать геокодирование.

Comment: [Страны, регионы, города](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/21949/).

Comment: [База GeoIP – страны и города, январь 2011](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/112413/)

Answer (score 2):

От Google: [API Карт Google](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) (ограничение на 2500 запросов в сутки). [Пример использования](http://www.telnet80.com/2010/09/address-validation-using-google-maps.html).

Answer (score 1):

Ну в нете вообще поиском не воспользоваться.

[База GeoIP – страны и города, июнь 2011 (+скрипт обновления)](http://netload.biz/2011/06/08/geoip4/).

+ использовать автозаполнение на Jquery допустим.

Comment: Ну попробуй сам догадаться что дальше делать-то... в чем проблема я не пойму, я дал направлени, даль =it настолько сложно погуглить?